# MsSql Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server

Can someone help me with this error?
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure gen048upload, Line 101
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

here is my code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[gen048upload]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @fileDate varchar(20)


AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @IerrorCode int
    DECLARE @error int,

        @tDay varchar(2),
        @tMonth varchar(2),
        @tYear varchar(4)

SET @tMonth= MONTH(GETDATE())
SET @tDay= DAY(GETDATE())
SET @tYear= Year(GETDATE())



DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (
    tempRow varchar(1000)
)

--  DECLARE @command varchar(1000)
--  SET @command = 'copy Y:\FTP\RMT\' + @fileDate + '.txt'
--  INSERT into @tempTable EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @command


DECLARE @fne_count int
SET @fne_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tempTable WHERE tempRow = 'The system cannot find the file specified.')




 IF @fne_count = 0
 BEGIN
     BEGIN TRAN  
        DECLARE @fileName varchar(100)
        SET @fileName = @fileDate + '.txt'


    CREATE TABLE #temp1
    (
        WHOLEROW varchar(8000)
    )


    DECLARE @CMD varchar(8000)
    SET @CMD = 'BULK INSERT #temp1
    FROM ''Y:\FTP\RMT\' +@fileName+ '''
    WITH (DATAFILETYPE = ''char'', KEEPNULLS, FIRSTROW=1, MAXERRORS=0, ROWTERMINATOR =  '''+char(0x0A)+''')'
    EXEC(@CMD)


    SET @error=0
    SET @error =  @error + @@ERROR


    DECLARE @Flag bigint,@msg varchar(200)

    IF EXISTS(SELECT ISNULL(MAX(flag),0) FROM gen_048)
        BEGIN

            SET @Flag =(SELECT ISNULL(MAX(flag),0) FROM gen_048)+1
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @Flag = 1
        END

--      DELETE FROM #temp1 WHERE WHOLEROW IS NULL
--      DELETE FROM #temp1 WHERE WHOLEROW like '%Hostdate|Book Type|CCY|Portfolio|GUAVA |Chart Code Name|Input|Native debit amount|Native credit amount|Base Amount|Counterparty|Acct|Deal|Product|Source|Native amount%'
--      DELETE FROM #temp1 WHERE WHOLEROW like '%||||CHART CODE||Date|||||No|Ref|||%'
--      DELETE FROM #temp1 WHERE WHOLEROW = ''


    DECLARE @inputTable table(
        input_date varchar(100)
    )

IF EXISTS (
        SELECT fdate
        FROM gen048_fdate
        WHERE fdate IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW, '|', 8), CHAR(9), '')
                FROM #temp1
        )
)

        IF EXISTS(SELECT fdate FROM gen048_fdate WHERE fdate = @input_date)
        BEGIN
                SET @msg = 'Error: File Exists, Duplication is not allowed'
        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO gen048_fdate
            SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',8), CHAR(9), '') FROM #temp1
            SET @IerrorCode = @@ERROR
            IF (@IerrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM 


            INSERT INTO gen_048 (
                            accname,
                            add1,
                            add2,
                            zip,
                            add3,
                            add4,
                            add5,
                            accdate,
                            bzip,
                            uname,
                            accnum,
                            pin)

                        SELECT
                        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',0),
                        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',1),
                        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',2),
                        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',3),
                        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',4),
                        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',5),
                        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',6), 
                        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',7),
                        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',8),-- input date
                        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',9),
                        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',10),
                        dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',11)   
                        FROM #temp1
                        SET @IerrorCode = @@ERROR
                        IF (@IerrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM 


            SET @msg = 'File has been successfully uploaded'
        END

END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @msg = 'File for.' + @fileDate + 'not found. No file is uploaded.'
    END


    COMMIT TRAN
    SELECT @msg as msg, @fileDate as filedate



                        PROBLEM:
                            IF (@IerrorCode <> 0) 
                            BEGIN
                                ROLLBACK TRAN
                                SELECT @IerrorCode as msg
                            END 
  END
END

-- [dbo].[gen048upload] '07-07-2015'
```

Comment: The root cause of your problem is `WHERE fdate = @input_date`, and the `@input_date` might have multiple values.  Any of the answers below could be right, depending on what your intended logic is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT fdate
        FROM gen048_fdate
        WHERE fdate IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW, '|', 8), CHAR(9), '')
                FROM #temp1
            )
    )
```

update -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[gen048upload]
(
    @fileDate VARCHAR(20)
)
AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #temp

    CREATE TABLE #temp (WHOLEROW VARCHAR(8000))

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @SQL = 'BULK INSERT #temp1
        FROM ''Y:\FTP\RMT\' + @fileDate + '.txt' + '''
        WITH (DATAFILETYPE = ''char'', KEEPNULLS, FIRSTROW=1, MAXERRORS=0, ROWTERMINATOR =  ''' + CHAR(0x0A) + ''')'

        EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

        IF EXISTS (
                SELECT fdate
                FROM gen048_fdate
                WHERE fdate IN (
                        SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW, '|', 8), CHAR(9), '')
                        FROM #temp1
                    )
            )
        BEGIN

            SELECT 'Error: File Exists, Duplication is not allowed', @fileDate

        END
        ELSE BEGIN

            INSERT INTO gen048_fdate (fdate)
            SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',8), CHAR(9), '')
            FROM #temp1

            INSERT INTO gen_048 (accname, add1, add2, zip, add3, add4, add5, accdate, bzip, uname, accnum, pin)
            SELECT
                dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',0),
                dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',1),
                dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',2),
                dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',3),
                dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',4),
                dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',5),
                dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',6), 
                dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',7),
                dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',8),
                dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',9),
                dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',10),
                dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',11)   
            FROM #temp1

            SELECT 'File has been successfully uploaded', @fileDate

        END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()

        IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END

    END CATCH

END
```

Comment: Im having this problem now after I replace it with your code
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure gen048upload, Line 106
Must declare the scalar variable "@input_date".
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure gen048upload, Line 110
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

Comment: Please provide your `sp`

Comment: Thanks a lot~! you are a big help sir~! sorry I'm just a beginner in MsSql :)

Answer (score 0):

when you assign value in variable using query. Query must be return one value.
Please check this line

```
SET @input_date = (SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',8), CHAR(9), '') FROM #temp1)
```

In this line should be use aggregate function.
**Max()
Min()**